# ¿Cómo generar un APK con PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, phonegap

¡Hola! cree una aplicación web híbrida. La aplicación me genera una lista de gastos de un api, cuando la ejecuto en el navegador la lista se genera perfecta pero cuando la quiero ver en el dispositivo móvil no se me genera, solo los capos de la tabla. El APK lo genere con PhoneGap Build

**Imagen de la lista - Web**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen de la lista - Móvil**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código - HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar">
     <h3>Lista de Gastos</h3>
      <form class="form-inline">
       <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search">
       <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
      </form>
    </nav>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="listDate" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">FECHA</th>
                    <th scope="col">CONCEPTO</th>
                    <th scope="col">TRANSACCIÓN</th>
                    <th scope="col">VALOR</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

**Código - JS**

```
let url = 'http://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/api/v1/expenses';
let expenses;
let dates = document.getElementById('listDate');

/////Funcion  crear y agregar elementos////
function append(parent, son) {
return parent.appendChild(son);
};
function createNode(element) {
return document.createElement(element);
};


fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
expenses = data.expenses;
expenses.forEach(function(item) {
let  tbody = createNode('tbody'),
tr = createNode('tr'),
tdF = createNode('td'),
tdC = createNode('td'),
tdT = createNode('td'),
tdG = createNode('td'),


textF = document.createTextNode(`${item.date}`);
textC = document.createTextNode(`${item.concept}`);
textT = document.createTextNode(`${item.transaction_type.name}`);
textG = document.createTextNode('$'+`${item.amount}`);

append(dates, tbody);
append(tbody, tr);

append(tr, tdF);
append(tdF, textF);

append(tr, tdC);
append(tdC, textC);

append(tr, tdT);
append(tdT, textT);

append(tr, tdG);
append(tdG, textG);


});
});
```

Comment: lo mas probable es que tu problema este en el config de phonegap

Comment: cuando la ejecutas en la app de emulador te pasa lo mismo?, podrias verificar que la funcion se este ejecutando incluyendo un console.log que se puede verificar en el CMD. SALUDOS

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre algunas cosas que puedes probar:

1) Intenta redimensionando en en navegador y verifica que la tabla no se te pierda, osea que tu app sea responsiva.
2) Cambia tu código dinamico

```
textF = document.createTextNode(`${item.date}`);
```

Pon algo estatico a ver si te sale

```
textF = document.createTextNode('2018-01-01');
```

3)Es posible que tengas un error de javascript, intenta con una depuración remota
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews?hl=es

Comment: Hola! Según mi profesor mi código esta bien, sino que me falta algo en PhoneGap

Comment: Pero el phonegad te está cargando bien la página en el webview, si fuera del phonegap no saldría nada, para mi sigue siendo un error cargando alguna librería javascript.